# Angular Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(rebaseRootRelativeCssUrls

Tags: angular

Angular
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(rebaseRootRelativeCssUrls

Answer (score 0):

i just changed
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1100.5",
to
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1000.6",

in Package.json file and worked for me